# jQuery plugin and can we collate data in a method IN a plugin before actually calling the plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if my question invalidates how plugins are suppose to work.

But here is my intent.

I have dynamic content on a page. Once the page is loaded, all needed data is available but the dynamic data only shows when a user clicks on certain buttons.

BUT, since a user will not click on all the buttons - when he/she clicks on any particular button I THEN want to gobble up some data on the page (certain data pertaining to the button), and send an ajax request.

Here would be the order of things.
1. user clicks on button
2. as the page dynamically changes (reformats table data and changes display).
3. As each table row item is built, I WANT to STORE some data from that row.
4. Once all rows are build and I have my obj of stored data THEN i call my plugin.

My question - for #3 - instead of creating a temp obj to store the data somewhere in the page and then pass that into the plugin when I call it. Could I use one of the plugin methods to handle that - to store that data? Is that bad form?

for example:

```
for each TR that is built.
   $.pluginName.methodName(storeData)
end;
```

once all the data is stored (table built), I just call my plugin. Since that *storeData* is already within my plugin, I can just use it?

my guess is this is bad form as I haven't initilized my plugin yet, set up the options etc.. so this dataset (storeData) will just be some rogue item in my plugin. I understand my other option is just create a local obj, push the data into it and when I call my plugin, just pass it in then.

Does this make sense? I am trying to be succinct here.

Comment: Before I make any assumptions about your methods, is it possible for you to store the data about the rows in a `data-whatever="something"` attribute? That way you don't need to do any object pushing and can just iterate over certain rows to get the data you want from within the plugin?

Comment: Actually both - I *do* need to add that to some elems but there is also other data that I need to make some visual choices based on other data. But yeah, your feelings are correct in one implementation of my plan.